# Store Image into SD Card using date and number

Tags: android, android-sdcard

i am using custom camera to capture images and saving into sd card using datetime, like below:

```
// Create a media file name
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
File mediaFile;
mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
return mediaFile;
```

But i have to make a small change in file name, like existing name looks like below:

```
IMG_20140312_162137.jpg
```

Now i want whenever user start capturing images, need to **start counting from 001**,

for an example for **1 image IMG_20140312_001.jpg**, for **2 image IMG_20140312_002.jpg** and so on.

Comment: What'll happen after "999"? It's better to keep it as "1,2,3....." instead of "001,002,003....."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
File mediaFile;
mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + getNextNumber() +".jpg");
return mediaFile;




public String getNextNumber(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
          "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int default = 0;


    int value = prefs.getInt("PICTURE_COUNT", default); 
    prefs.edit().putInt("PICTURE_COUNT", ++value).commit();
    return convertToDesiredFormat(value);
}

String convertToDesiredFormat(int value){
      String toReturn = null;
      if (value > 99)
         toReturn = Integer.toString(value);
      else if (value > 9)
         toReturn = "0" + Integer.toString(value);
      else if (value >= 0)
         toReturn = "00" + Integer.toString(value);
      return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: amazing solution bro :) actually you deserve +1000 for this

Answer (score 0):

then store the image count in one share preference and count increase as u click any no of picture  and then again update share preference for next time simple because if u clear your app from stack then next time this count is have to start from last that why we use share preference

Answer (score 0):

Append one counter at the end of your image name as below :

```
 int count=0;
 String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
            + "IMG_" + timeStamp +" _00 "+ count +".jpg");
     count++;

    return mediaFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to keep the track of the counter with shared preference when your application reopens

```
SharedPreferences pref;

    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;

        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("counter", 
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        edit = pref.edit();

edit.putInt("count" ,count++);
edit.commit();


and the get the count when next time you use the count

mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp +pref.getString("count", 0))+ ".jpg");
```